# Method created in 2nd class skipped while running 2 classes in Testng using xml

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I had created 2 classes having 3 methods/test in these 2 classes. 2 methods/test in 1st class and 3rd method/test is in 2nd class. But when I run these using xml 1st class runs both the tests  and tests pass where as method/test in 2nd class skips.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name= "Expedia Call Tracker">
    <test name="Expedia Home Smoke Testcases">
        <classes>
            <class name="ExpediaCallTracker.Expedia"/>
            <class name="ExpediaCallTracker.ExpediaCreateSale" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

First Class :

package ExpediaCallTracker;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Expedia {

public String e;

WebDriver expedia = new FirefoxDriver();


@Test(priority=1)

public void ExpediaLogin()
{

    expedia.manage().window().maximize();
    expedia.get("http://fedev.teleperformanceusa.com/Expedia/ExpediaCallTracker/Account/Login");

    expedia.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("kochhar.5");
    expedia.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("Password11");
    expedia.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginForm']/form/fieldset/p/input")).click();

}


@Test(priority=2)
public void ExpediaDashSale()

{

    expedia.findElement(By.linkText("Sale - HWW/EAN")).click();
}
```

}

```
Second Class :

package ExpediaCallTracker;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Optional;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class ExpediaCreateSale {

private static final WebDriver d = null;

public ExpediaCreateSale()
{

}

WebDriver expedia = d;          

@Test
public void ExpediaCreate(WebDriver d)
{


    expedia.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Select LineOfBusiness = new Select(expedia.findElement(By.id("lineOfBusiness")));
    LineOfBusiness.selectByIndex(1);
    expedia.findElement(By.id("sourceCode")).sendKeys("abcdefgh");

    WebElement Upsell = expedia.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/section[2]/form/fieldset/div[6]/input[1]"));
    Upsell.click();

    WebElement SaleCall =expedia.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/section[2]/form/fieldset/div[8]/input[1]"));
    SaleCall.click();

    expedia.findElement(By.id("checkInDate")).sendKeys("09/14/2016");

    Select numberOfNights = new Select(expedia.findElement(By.id("numberOfNights")));
    numberOfNights.selectByIndex(1);

    WebElement PaymentMethod = expedia.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/section[2]/form/fieldset/div[9]/div[6]/input[1]"));
    PaymentMethod.click();

    Select currency = new Select(expedia.findElement(By.id("currency")));
    currency.selectByIndex(70);
    expedia.findElement(By.id("grossBooking")).sendKeys("123456");
    expedia.findElement(By.id("itineraryNumber")).sendKeys("123456789");
    expedia.findElement(By.id("remark")).sendKeys("Itinery       number         saved.");
    expedia.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='body']/section[2]    /form/fieldset/p/input[1]")).click();
}
```

}

Can anyone suggest what should I try to do ?

Comment: can you share your `testng.xml`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name= "Expedia Call Tracker">
<test name="Expedia Home Smoke Testcases">
<classes>

<class name="ExpediaCallTracker.Expedia"/>
<class name="ExpediaCallTracker.ExpediaCreateSale">
<!-- <methods>
    <include name="ExpediaCreate" />
    
    
     <exclude name="testMakeOrder" />
    
   </methods> -->
  </class>


</classes>

</test>


</suite>

Comment: it looks good, can you edit your question and put the code of both the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Test method ExpediaCreate that takes a parameter WebDriver  is causing this issue. To fix this, follow the same approach as Expedia class and it should work.

Moreover, you have not initialized webdriver instance variable d in the ExpediaCreateSale class. Once you initialize the driver instance, it is available in your test methods so you dont have to pass as a paramater.

You dont have to have this line of code also.

```
private static final WebDriver d = null;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I tried the same but it doesn't work for me.